# Pass jQuery variable to CSS

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to dynamically calculate the `min-width` of `body` based on the number of `div.columns` that exist on the page, plus a padding of 180px. This is the code I'm using:

```
function countColumns() {
    var columns =  $('.column').size(); 
    document.write(columns)
}

$('body').css('min-width', (parseInt(columns) * 120) + 180 + 'px') );
```

Any clue as to why its not working?

Comment: `columns` is local to `countColumns()`, so you cannot access it from the outside. Also, your call to `parseInt()` looks unnecessary since `size()` already returns an `int` (and you should use `length` instead, btw).

Comment: ...and as if that weren´t enough, you never use `countColumns()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to the scope of the `columns` variable. You need to either make it global, or assign it to the result of the function, the latter being preferable. Try this:

```
function countColumns() {
    return $('.column').size(); 
}

$('body').css('min-width', (parseInt(countColumns()) * 120) + 180 + 'px') );
```

Note, the `parseInt` is redundant as the `size()` method will always return an integer.

Comment: I used this instead and it worked great `$('body').css('min-width', ((countColumns()) * 120) + 180 + 'px');` Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since `columns` variable is defined inside the function it is not accessible outside it. You should define it in an outer or global scope. Try this.

```
var columns;
function countColumns() {
    columns =  $('.column').size(); 
    document.write(columns)
}

$('body').css('min-width', ((parseInt(columns) * 120) + 180) + 'px') );
```

Alternatively you can even call the function which will return the number of columns. In this way you don't have to maintain the variable. Also in `countColumns` function I am using `lenght` property of the jQuery object which gives the same result and also avoids one function call. Try this

```
   function countColumns() {
        return  $('.column').length; 
    }

    $('body').css('min-width', ((countColumns * 120) + 180) + 'px') );
```

Comment: You also have to call the `countColumns()` function... on the other hand, there's no reason to use the global variable if the function would just return the value.

Comment: Also, make sure you´re running the script once the DOM has loaded.

Comment: As a side note: consider [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) for things like this, it's wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

you're setting the column variable from within the scope of the function, try this instead

```
var columns
function countColumns() {
    columns =  $('.column').size(); 
    document.write(columns)
}

$('body').css('min-width', (parseInt(columns) * 120) + 180 + 'px') );
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var minWidth = ($('.column').length * 120) + 180);
  $('body').css('min-width', (minWidth + 'px') );

});
```

Never seen anyone use `min-width` on `<body>` though :P